# How to tell that the strings selected randomly out of a list are the same

Tags: python, string, list, random

I have this question; I'll sum it up in steps

1. Make the program add 7 animals to a list via inputs (DONE)
2. Make the program select 3 random animals from that list (DONE)
3. If the animals selected are all the same, print 'Bingo!' ; if not, loop the input until the user presses 'X' or gets a 'Bingo!'.

I'm having trouble with the last step, and I've tried searching everywhere and tried many methods but the code isn't doing the right thing. Here's the code:

```
import random

bingoList=[]
generatedList=[]

def generateCards():
    for i in range(0,3):   
        print(random.choice(bingoList))
        generatedList.append(a)

for i in range(0,7):
    a=input("Enter an animal: ")
    if (a.isdigit()==False):
        bingoList.append(a)
    else:
        printprint("You are not allowed to input numbers; program stopping...")
        exit()

print("All the animals have been stored, let's start the game..")

generateCards()
```

Comment: _"I've tried searching everywhere and tried many methods but the code isn't doing the right thing."_ Your code doesn't appear to be trying any methods at all. Please share with us the last thing you tried.

Comment: @Kevin if (generatedList==a,a,a):
    print("Bingo")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly, you should use a set:

```
if len(set(bingoList)) == 1:
    print('Bingo!')
```